How do I delete these verts that were extruded instead being connected with the rest of the model?
The problem is the verts sticking out and they aren't possible to delete for whatever reasons.



what doesn't work? Pressing X doesn't give you an option to delete vertices or it doesn't open at all or what exactly is happening?

press Alt Z to toggle the x-ray, this way you'll be able to select the vertices behind, maybe this is your problem here?
